# How many vowels and consonants should you keep at the end of the turn in Scrabble?

Tags: scrabble

I'm no professional player at all, but it seems like a balanced rack could be keeping a certain number of vowels/consonants. Considering there are 100 letter tiles, 56 consonants and 42 vowels, with a ratio of 56:42 or 1.33 consonant:vowel ratio, keeping a ratio as close as possible could be good maybe. Here is my idea for ideal consonant:vowel ratios making it as close to 1.33 as I can:

> 6 tiles left: 3 consonants, 3 vowels; 1 ratio
>
> 5 tiles left: 3 consonants, 2 vowels; 1.5 ratio
>
> 4 tiles left: 2 consonants, 2 vowels; 1 ratio
>
> 3 tiles left: 2 consonants, 1 vowel; 2 ratio
>
> 2 tiles left: 1 consonant, 1 vowel; 1 ratio
>
> 1 tiles left: 1 consonant; indefinite ratio

I know it heavily depends on the current board as well the tile bag, but for general purposes, what would be a good ratio for each number of tiles remaining at the end of the turn?

Comment: Why would you aim for the distribution of the bag, and not the distribution of the words you're trying to create?

Comment: @Nij as the bag distribution is based on real world distributions (from a copy of a daily newspaper If I recall correctly) there is a certain logic here. Ultimately the board position, what letters are accessible and what your actual tiles are (3 Es anyone) probably play more important roles.

Comment: Yes, the letter distribution as used in written English - but the game isn't played by forming full coherent sentences, hence the question of relevance, versus just the targeted words.